# Is it symfony bad practice to inject entity manager in repository?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity

I have som calculations that I'd like to keep outside of the controller, ideally in a repository, but would it be bad practice to inject the entity manager in a repo to pull data from other entities into it?

Comment: For what? Extends your repository classes with `Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository` and you can get the EntityManager in your repository with `$this->getEntityManager()`

Comment: From other entities? While technically it's "accessing data" it'll probably break SRP. I'd move that logic to a Service with the needed repositories. Unless it's heavily coupled with your entities (you are doing mostly joins, but don't seem like that's what you need).